# SharePoint: Open Word doc link in same window

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-word

SharePoint 2010
Word 2007

Does anyone know how to have a link within a Word document, that is opened inside a SharePoint browser window, which, when the link is clicked it will open a second Word document in the same browser window?

```
SharePoint 2010 Browser Window 1
   Open Word Doc 1
      Click on link within Word Doc 1
   Word Doc 2 is opened (in the same browser window)
      If I click 'Close' in the 'Word Viewer', Word Doc 2 will close and I am back to Word Doc 1
```

Word 2007 does not like JavaScript to open a new window with _self.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably better suited for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

That being said, I think this is your answer from TechNet:

[Configure the default open behavior for browser-enabled documents (Office Web Apps)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx)

A little PowerShell and you'll be rocking and rolling.